# Setting and getting model values in OpenUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to play with OpenUi5. I want to set 'artificial model' change the value and print it.
My code:

```
onInit: function () {
    this.getView().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel());
    this.getView().getModel().setData({"name":"Jon"});
    this.getView().getModel().setProperty("name", "Ann");

    var name = this.getView().getModel().getProperty("name");
    window.alert(name);
```

It says that `name` is `null`.
Why is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to look into this tutorial from SAP:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.54.8/#/topic/e5310932a71f42daa41f3a6143efca9c

but for a quick answer:
you are missing a `/`, and you dont need the `"` in you json

```
this.getView().getModel().setData({name:"Jon"});
...
var name = this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/name");
```

obv same for the set property line

also for easier readability of you code i'd do smth in the lines of:

```
onInit: function () {
    var oYourModel = new JSONModel({
            name: "Jon"
    });
    this.getView().setModel(oYourModel, "modelName");
    this.getView().getModel("modelName").setProperty("/name", "Ann");

    var name = this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/name");
    window.alert(name);
```